# Multiple UIViews, passing methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, multiple-views

I have two `UIView` contained in a `UIViewController` - `firstView` and `secondView` - that I initialize pragmatically. I have a `UILabel` in the `firstView`, and a `UIButton` in the `secondView`. I would like the button in the second view to change the label in the first view. In the implementation file of the second view I have the following code:

```
- (void) changeLabel: (UIButton *) sender{
    firstView *view = [[firstView alloc] init];
    view.label.text = @"Changed Text";
}
```

However I figured out that the above method just initializes a new class of firstView and does not link to the existing `UIView`. How can I change properties of `firstView` from within `secondView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create properties in your view controller's header file for the views:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *firstView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *label;
```

When you create the view and label assign them to the properties:

```
self.firstView = // create your view here

self.label = // create your label here
```

Create a button property on your UIView object so you can access it later:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *button;
```

Then in your view controller file, when you create everything, access the view's button property and add a target, like this:

```
[firstView.button addTarget:self action:@selector(changeLabel) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then you can simply have the method your button calls be like this:

```
- (void)changeLabel {
    self.label.text = @"Changed Text.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Still trying to figure it out though. My method for the button is contained inside secondView, thus self.label.text points to secondView and not the ViewController. Is there a way around this?